# LESS generated CSS not being applied - stumped! (VS 2013 LESS bundling)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, css, asp.net-mvc-4, less

I'm completely stumped - what am I missing?

I have a LESS file called Main.less - and VS 2013 automatically generates Main.min.css whenever I save it.

The CSS generated is fine - no errors. When I copy the generated CSS to my Style.css (to verify) it is applied correctly.

I bundle the Main.min.css generated from the LESS file via the usual bundleconfig along with other css files (mainly my bootstrap and site css).

When I run the site, I can see the styles in the referenced bundled source - but the style is not applied! What am I missing?

(here is the .LESS)

```
@color1: #FFA114;
@color2: #69b1fa;
@std_border: 2px;

.rounded {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sel_1 {
    .rounded;
    border: @std_border solid @color1;
}
```

(here is the .css as it appears in the minified bundle on the browser)

```
.rounded{border-radius:10px}.sel_1{border-radius:10px;border:2px solid #ffa114}
```

I can only imagine something is wrong somewhere so that the browsers (latest Chrome and IE) don't even apply the styles. No idea what...

EDIT: UPDATE:

I also referred the generated min.css directly

```
<link href="/Content/Main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and on browser-> view source -> click on the .css you see the following

```
.rounded{border-radius:10px}.sel_1{border-radius:10px;border:2px solid #ffa114}.sel_2{border-radius:10px;border:2px solid #ffa114;border-color:#69b1fa}.asel_1{border-radius:10px;border:2px solid #ffa114;border-style:dashed}.asel_2{border-radius:10px;border:2px solid #ffa114;border-color:#69b1fa;border-style:dashed}.map_sel{border:3px double #69b1fa}.line{border-bottom:2px #ffa114 solid;padding:10px}
```

And the styles **are still not applied!**

Comment: if it is already minified why bundling?

Comment: Ehsan, just convenient to keep it all together. But what should that matter? (let me try linking the file separately and see what happens...)

Comment: Bundling will also reduce the number of trips to the server to get the content. Can you show us where you define this css bundle from from bundle.config file?

Comment: @swestfall the effect is the same whether I bundle or not... please see my comment above. Even if I link the file separately it still doesn't apply.

Comment: Order matters with css so I wanted to see in which order you where bundling your css files. Could you provide a fiddle with the issue or a link to the site?

Comment: The css you have posted is fine.  If you are getting no errors (404's) in your dev tools, then you need to check your markup has the correct css classes applied. Create a basic page with a couple of elements and a link to the stylesheet and see if that works.

Comment: Do you have caching on?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I "solved" it (not really...) by deleting my Site.css and moving all my styles to the Main.less, and it worked. I have absolutely no idea why. I did not have duplicate styles, my Site.css was just fine and so was the LESS generate .css, but it wouldn't apply. Anyway, it works and I'll leave it at that.